# Xpath - Find element with string like %str%

Tags: xpath

I have a centered `h3` tag on my page. Is it possible to check if the element has text by using something like `like %needle%`?

**Html:**

```
<center><h3>hello folks</h3></center>
```

**Xpath**

```
//center/h3[.="hello folks"]
```

Is something like the following possible?

```
//center/h3[Like("folks")]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

`//center/h3[contains(.,'folks')]`